# How to show zoomable/ magnifying part of imageview into another imageview like flipkart?

Tags: java, android

**My layout as follows :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewZooming"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 <utility.ImageMagnifier
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/banner_image"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewOriginal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewZooming"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewZooming" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ImageMagnifier.java Code as follows:

```
public class ImageMagnifier extends ImageView {

private PointF zoomPos;
private boolean zooming = false;
private Matrix matrix;
private Paint paint;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private BitmapShader shader;
private int sizeOfMagnifier = 200;

public ImageMagnifier(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    zoomPos = new PointF(0, 0);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    paint = new Paint();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    zoomPos.x = event.getX();
    zoomPos.y = event.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            zooming = true;
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            zooming = false;
            this.invalidate();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!zooming) {
        buildDrawingCache();
    } else {

        bitmap = getDrawingCache();
        shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y);
        paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, sizeOfMagnifier, paint);

    }
  }
}
```

I am using above code for magnifying/zooming some part of imageview using touch. But I was unable to see that particular zooming image in another imageview. Here I am using canvas.drawCircle method for zooming.

[image]

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you check my provided image at the section "enter image description here" you will definitely understand the thing and also If u placed cursor at web version of flipkart item images you will see that part showing at another view with some zooming. I want that part implementation in my android app.

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/ST4My82Y)

Comment: getting null pointer exception while using the above mentioned Code @pskink

Comment: just call `setContentView(new V(this));` in `Activity#onCreate` method

Comment: Yes. It's working.but I have to use it in a particular position of a layout.

Comment: what do you mean? what `particular position`?

Comment: Previously I am using imageView top of the screen with height 250dp and Image shows perfectly. But here I am not getting full image. Showing some part of Image.Is it possible to use your view in my current layout?

Comment: if it is zoomed it has to be shown partially, otherwise there is no need to zoom it, and yes, every view can be used in xml layout

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of lower part rectangle that showing zoom able part?

Comment: sure: you have the source code, read it , analize it and change it

Comment: Problem is that zoom able part is also showing at the same view, I want zoom able part in different view.

Comment: so split my view into two separate views

Comment: I tried but unable to do that, Can you provide me updated source code where upper portion showing original one and lower portion showing zoom able part.

Comment: My layout showing perfect image but while load the custom layout using code unable to get whole image perfectly. My exact requirement is original a large image show upper part of layout and zoomable part show lower part of that root layout.

Comment: ok,  so create such a layout,  whats  the problem here?

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the function using here for zooming control? Actually I want to reduce the zoom because zoomable part is stretched badly here.

Comment: what is stretched badly? the bitmap is drawn using `Canvas#drawBitmap` method

Comment: Yes.But how can I control the zooming?If I want a slight zoom how can I handle this?

Comment: by changing the matrix

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your valuable help friend.Your demo is just awesome.